# Работа Apple Pay через UIWebView

Tags: ios

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.
Проблема следующего толка: есть робокасса, которая принимает платежи через Apple Pay. Оплата у меня организована внутри приложения через Web форму. Соотвественно так же открывается и оплата через Apple Pay.

Единственное место, где я смог найти схожую проблему, это тут: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71796
У человека тоже проблема, через UIWebView не дают оплатить.

У Apple есть вроде как фраза, что "If your app uses a web-based interface for purchasing goods and services" ( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/ApplePay_Guide/CreateRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014764-CH3-SW2), что надо просто в код возвращать. Но дальше опять надо указывать параметры, которые должны, вроде как, всё же деньги переводить на счёт компании, а не агрегатора.

Робокасса пишет, что оплачивать надо через Safari. Но у меня же WebView, а не Safari.

Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, что сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону SFSafari​View​Controller

Comment: К сожалению не удалось найти, как открыть request в SafariViewController. 
На пробу WKWebView так же не дал результатов.

Comment: `let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL....)!)` если нужен  POST, то это делается через автосабмит формы находящейся на вашем сервере.

Comment: У меня идёт получение адреса сервера агрегатора, по которому я перехожу и открываю в UIWebView. И именно к этому адресу нужно добавить POST. Тут нет участия никакой формы моего сервера.

Comment: По другому иногда не получается. Делается страничка которая формирует форму с нужными полями, получающая данные для формирования по GET от приложения, размещается на своём сервере и грузится приложением она, дальше выполняется  POST тем же  javascript  на агрегатор. Всякие webview  предоставляют слишком много информации приложению о контенте, поэтому в некоторых агрегаторах запрещены в принципе. Приходится строить костыли.

Comment: Здесь по сути, я так понимаю, надо отказаться от webview, воспользовавшись SFSafariViewController, где через костыль по добавлению POST параметров через собственный сервер мы и открываем страницу агрегатора? 
Мы можем в SFSafariViewController отслеживать изменение URL? Как в WebView мы через shouldStartLoadWithRequest вытаскиваем из request URL

Comment: К сожалению - никак. Контроллер не возвращает никаких событий, кроме успешной загрузки первого url и нажатия "Done". Поэтому нужно искать другие способы проверки статуса оплаты.